# Array in Datatable make customise in array and display coluns according new columns

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

While using data table display dynamic data takes array as input with customize field in array.

Comment: Can you please ask a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Give any specific class to the `<table>` element which is assigned as the data table

**JS**

```js
var BindDatatable = function (data) {
        table = $('.datatable').DataTable({
            retrieve: true,
            data: data,
            columns: [
                { data: 'EmployeeID' },
                { data: 'EmployeeName' },
                { data: 'DOB', type: 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy', targets: 0, width: '100px' },
                { data: 'Salary' },
                { data: 'DepartmentName' },
                { data: 'CountryName' },
                { data: 'StateName' },
                { data: 'CityName' },
                {
                    data: null,
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var html = "";
                        html += '<button class="btn btn-primary" data-viewtype="' + data.EmployeeID + '" id="' + data.EmployeeID + '" title="View"><span class="fa fa-user"></span></button>&nbsp';
                        html += '<button class="btn btn-success" data-edittype="' + data.EmployeeID + '" id="' + data.EmployeeID + '" title="Edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></button>&nbsp';
                        html += '<button class="btn btn-danger" data-deletetype="' + data.EmployeeID + '" id="' + data.EmployeeID + '" title="Delete"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>';
                        return html;
                    }
                }
            ],
        });
    };
```

**HTML**

```html
    <table id="table_id" class="datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmployeeID</th>
                <th>EmployeeName</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```